# Count the number of columns which are not null

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

**room:**

```
+---------+---------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
| room_id | room_no | room_stat | room_name   | player_a_id | player_b_id | turn_of |
+---------+---------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
|       1 |       1 |         0 | blah        |           0 |           0 |       0 |
|       2 |       5 |         0 | second room |           1 |           3 |       0 |
|       3 |       3 |         0 | 3rd room    |           0 |           0 |       0 |
|       4 |       4 |         0 | 4th room    |           0 |           0 |       0 |
+---------+---------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
```

i want to count how many players are inside that room for example:

- if player_a_id !=0 or !NULL AND player_b_id !=0 or !NULL then the
  count will be **2**
- if only player_a_id!=0 or player_b_id!=0 then
  the count will be **1**
- else if both player_a_id and player_b_id is
  NULL then return **0**;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like:

```
select room_id,
       ((case when player_a_id <> 0 and player_a_id is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when player_b_id <> 0 and player_b_id is not null then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as NumInRoom
from room;
```

The comparisons to NULL are actually unnecessary.  The following have the same effect:

```
select room_id,
       ((case when player_a_id <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when player_b_id <> 0 then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as NumInRoom
from room;
```

Comment: most answers are right but this one was the first and what i currently now using. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the shortest way since `MySQL` supports boolean arithmetic.

```
SELECT  room_no,
        (player_a_id IS NOT NULL AND player_a_id <> 0) + 
        (player_b_id IS NOT NULL AND player_b_id <> 0) AS totalNumber
FROM    room
```

*thanks peterm* `:)`

Comment: with one correction `OR`s should be `AND`s in your query [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6db3/4)

Answer (score 1):

```
select
   room_id, 
   (least(coalesce(player_a_id, 0), 1) + least(coalesce(player_b_id, 0), 1)) 
    as player_count
from room;
```

`coalesce` chooses the first non-NULL entry in its list, so it will come up with the actual player ID, or 0 if NULL.

`least` chooses the lowest value of the coalesced values, so any player ID > 1 will only count as 1.

Add the two, and you have the non-0, non-NULL player count for that room.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify greatly by considering what values the id *is*, rather than is *not*:

```
select 2
  - ifnull(player_a_id = 0, 1)
  - ifnull(player_b_id = 0, 1)
from room
```

See [this in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed223/4)

This query is using the *negative* of the test, and *subtracting* when true.

Note that in mysql, `true` is `1` and `false` is `0` allowing you to simply *add* the tests numerically rather than use case statements to convert tests to numbers as would be required in all other databases with which I'm familiar.

Comment: what if `player_a_id` or `player_b_id` is null?

Comment: @JW웃 OK - you got me :) I've fixed it and created a fiddle. Thanks - I'll remember that mistake. Cheers.